# I have issue of cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am new at iOS development and i have some issue of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method of `UITableView`.

In my application i have multiple rows in `UITableView`. when i want to see each row then obviously i need to scroll `UITableView`.also in `UITableView` i added `UITextField` to each  `UITableViewCell` . when i add value
of UITextField in DataBase then its work properly but when i want to edit values of `UITextField` and i add values of TextField in DataBase then problem is created.

PROBLEM  :-  If i want to add all editable values of TextField in DataBase then i must need to be scroll `UITableView` up to down. if i do not  scroll then invisible TextField is not add in DataBase :( **Here in my Application add and editing are in same `UIViewController` base on ID that i passed.**

by Googling i also found that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not called for all rows. It is only called for visible rows and then called for additional rows as the user scrolls to them. Old rows are also destroyed as they go off the screen and it will request the cells again if the user scrolls back up.

so, please help me how can i solve my problem,

**EDIT FOR MORE EASY TO UNDERSTAND MY PROBLEM :**

For Example :

**I have two UIViewController.**

1 - FirstViewController
  2 - SecondViewController

in `FirstViewController` display all list of Name in `UITableView` and it has two choice either select name in `UITableView` or add new data by tapp BarButton from `UINavigationBar` .This both processed adding and editing are done in same ViewController called SecondViewController . data (or values) Add by `SecondViewController` is working properly 
     But  when i select any row ( or name ) from FirstViewController  then related ID pass to `SecondViewController` and all information are display on TextField base on ID. here all values are get from DATABASE and i store it to `NSMutableDictionary` and then it store on textField by access  KEY of Dictionary. but values are store in TextField which are visible. invisible TextField not store values even i get from DATABASE . so i must need to first scroll UITableView.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why don't you just add the visible TextField to DataBase and when scrolled add the visible TextField again. You need ID to distinguish different TextField (Maybe you can use the TableViewCell's reuseIdentifier).

Comment: when i am in editing mode then whole Values are store in different UITextField that  are subview of UITableViewCell. i can display only some values of TextField. if i edit only first Value of TextField then invisible values of TextField are not Add to DATABASE.

Comment: Before you enter editing mode, save all the values into DataBase. Just modify the DataBase when you have edited some TextField. Can this solve?

Comment: i already did it  :) but it is not work ...main point is that scroll of UITableView :(

Comment: let's see your code, particularly `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Post your code so that we can help you in detail.

Comment: its not an issue of scrollView or UITableView.. its purely a data management or data handling issue... can you tell us how u are maintaining the data to display on tableView, & each row in tableView corresponds to an object in each row of ur database table..?

Comment: @vishy,@sunkehappy,@alan duncan ...thanks for helping me and please refere my edited Question... edit Question for more easy to understand :) thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Then implement like given below

Get the database value and store it in `NSMutableDictionary` and accessible through out by declaring in interface or `.h` file.

Then when each time your `tableView` or `textField` loads read the values from dictionary and display.

And in your `textFieldDidEnd` or `textFieldDidChange` delegate get the data from `textField` & save/store back to your dictionary with the same key. This time it just replaces the old value as you know.

At last just save all the dictionary values into your database on `backAction` or `viewWillDisappear` method.

This should work for you, if not let me know.